# Calculation on list of numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to do some calculation (mean, sum, etc.) on a list containing numpy arrays.
For example:

> list = [array([2, 3, 4]),array([4, 4, 4]),array([6, 5, 4])]

How can retrieve the mean (for example) ?
In a list like `[4,4,4]` or a numpy array like `array([4,4,4])` ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

EDIT : Sorry, I didn't explain properly what I was aiming to do : I would like to get the mean of i-th index of the arrays. For example, for index 0 :

> (2+4+6)/3 = 4

I don't want this :

> (2+3+4)/3 = 3

Therefore the end result will be

> [4,4,4] / and not [3,4,5]

Comment: Are these arrays always the same shape?  So that `np.array(list)` or `np.stack(list)` produces a 2d array?

Comment: Yes, they have the same shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `L` were a list of scalars then calculating the mean could be done using the straight forward expression:

```
sum(L) / len(L)
```

Luckily, this works unchanged on lists of arrays:

```
L = [np.array([2, 3, 4]), np.array([4, 4, 4]), np.array([6, 5, 4])]
sum(L) / len(L)
# array([4., 4., 4.])
```

For this example this happens to be quitea bit faster than the numpy function
`np.mean`

```
timeit(lambda: np.mean(L, axis=0))
# 13.708808058872819
timeit(lambda: sum(L) / len(L))
# 3.4780975924804807
```

Comment: Thank you! I've used this method and it worked properly

Answer (score 0):

Given a 1d array `a`, `np.mean(a)` should do the trick.

If you have a 2d array and want the means for each one separately, specify `np.mean(a, axis=1)`.

There are equivalent functions for `np.sum`, etc.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [np.array([2, 3, 4]),np.array([4, 4, 4]),np.array([6, 5, 4])]

np.mean(my_list,axis=0) #[4,4,4]
```

Note: Do not name your variable as `list` as it will shadow the built-ins

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and iterate through the elements of your array, if your list is not too big:

```
mean = []
for i in range(len(list)):
   mean.append(np.mean(list[i]))
```